# Is a spreaded Array pushed to another array by value or reference in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

**Example 1**

I have a code pushing one spreaded array into another:

```
const hobbies = ['Sports', 'Cooking'];
const activeHobbies = ['Hiking'];

activeHobbies.push(...hobbies);
console.log(activeHobbies); //['Hiking', 'Sports', 'Cooking']

hobbies.push('Skiing');
console.log(hobbies); //['Sports', 'Cooking', 'Skiing']
console.log(activeHobbies); //['Hiking', 'Sports', 'Cooking']
```

Is a spreaded array pushed same as `activeHobbies.push(hobbies[0], hobbies[1])` by values?

Why is it not `['Hiking', 'Sports', 'Cooking', 'Skiing']` in the last line ?

**Example 2**

```
const hobbies = ['Sports', 'Cooking'];
const activeHobbies = ['Hiking'];

activeHobbies.push(hobbies);
console.log(activeHobbies); //['Hiking', ['Sports', 'Cooking', 'Skiing']], why not ['Hiking', ['Sports', 'Cooking']] ?

hobbies.push('Skiing');
console.log(hobbies); //['Sports', 'Cooking', 'Skiing']
console.log(activeHobbies); //['Hiking', ['Sports', 'Cooking', 'Skiing']]
```

As I understand, `hobbies` array will be pushed to `activeHobbies` by reference without spreading like this `activeHobbies.push(hobbies)` and the new values will be added to `hobbies` array inside `activeHobbies` array, if new values are pushed to `hobbies` array, because it's pushed by reference. Is it correct?

But why the first console outputs `['Hiking', ['Sports', 'Cooking', 'Skiing']]` and not `['Hiking', ['Sports', 'Cooking']]` ?

Comment: For example 2, the reason is due to your brower logging a live reference of the object that is logged (so it's not showing the object at the time of being logged, but rather the object at the time you're observing the log - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a spreaded array pushed same as `activeHobbies.push(hobbies[0], hobbies[1])`?

Yes. This is true for all spread syntax function calls, not just `push`.

> Why does `activeHobbies` not change?

Because it's independent of `hobbies`, there is no connection, they're two separate arrays and you pushed `'Skiing'` only to one of them.

> the new values will be added to `hobbies` array […], if new values are pushed to `hobbies` array

Yes. Doesn't matter whether you're looking at the array via `activeHobbies[1]` or via the `hobbies` variable, it's the same object after all.

> Why the first console outputs `['Hiking', ['Sports', 'Cooking', 'Skiing']]` and not `['Hiking', ['Sports', 'Cooking']]`?

This is just an artifact of the [interactive `console.log` reprentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/1048572). It didn't actually output that before you pushed the value.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking to Example 1, when you pushed the spread values of `hobbies` to `activeHobbies`, that was a one-time operation in which the primitive values contained in the `hobbies` array were cloned and added to `activeHobbies`. The original `hobbies` array wasn’t altered, at all, and remains entirely independent of `activeHobbies`. So when you later add a new array item to `hobbies`, `activeHobbies` is entirely unaffected as the two arrays aren’t linked in any way and values added to one wouldn’t automatically appear in the other without being pushed to each. `Push` with the spread operator amounts to a one-time concatenation of two arrays.